# How can we calculate nth percentile using the Jmeter dashboard report results csv file?

Tags: jmeter

How can we calculate the correct nth percentile using generated the Jmeter dashboard report CSV file?

I tried to calculate percentile values using the below formula,

90th - reorder the generated CSV file records by Latency (High to Low). and removed the last 10% of the samples and got the highest value. But this is not equal with the summary report 90 pct value.

total samples 20775,
10 pct :  20775 * 10% = 2077

Removed top 2077 records from the CSV after sorting by latency High to low.
Highlighted value shows as the 90th pct value after removing top 10%

after removing first 2077 records

[image]

The calculated percentile values are different by nearly 200ms- 1 sec. How to validate these percentiles correctly? With Jmeter it considers all success and fail samples for these calculations. right?

- Jmeter: 5.4.1 v

Dashboard summary report values

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why just don't let JMeter to do this for you? The values in the Dashboard match the ones from the Aggregate Report or the ones generated by Excel's [PERCENTILE](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-percentile-function) function

[image]

If you want the different `nts` percentile i.e. something different from default values which are:

> - aggregate_rpt_pct1 : Defaults to 90
> - aggregate_rpt_pct2 : Defaults to 95
> - aggregate_rpt_pct3 : Defaults to 99

You can add i.e. the following line to [*user.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization):

```
aggregate_rpt_pct1=70
```

and both Aggregate Report and the Dashboard will display 70th percentile now instead of 90th.

Also your approach with "removing last 10% and taking the highest" is not very correct, the [formula for calculating the percentile](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-percentile-3126238) looks like:

```
 n = (P/100) x N
```

where N = number of values in the data set, P = percentile, and n = ordinal rank of a given value (with the values in the data set sorted from smallest to largest).